# Jquery and firefox not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've read as many topics as I could, but still I cannot find the resolution...

I've built many websites with jCarousel.js but this one is hitting me back so hard ;<

So, I'm trying to add jCarousel, easy stuff like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
     auto: 3000,
speed: 1000,
vertical: true,
   });
});
```

Above that I did include

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I was happy about using It fine on Chrome, but then I turned on FireFox and the happy stuff disappeared. 
FireBug shows, no errors, Chrome as well but the script doesn't work. After refreshing page It starts working. It seems like FireFox is not loading that part of the code, so there are no errors, as well no working script...

What should I do ;> ?

Comment: I assume the PHP is inserting the correct directory for the js.

Comment: I think we need more information---what is the expected output?

Comment: working script is the expected output xD  I did try to change the path without using PHP , without any result. After all I;ve noticed there are few times on Chrome it doesn't work as well, and displays Undefined is not a function. So It's even more strange for me, looks like the jcarousellite_1.0.1.js is not being loaded ;<

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess with a `Header set X-Content-Security-Policy` line in it?

Comment: nope I don't have it, should I add it ?

Comment: No, it was just in case you had some security stopping the request to code.jquery.com ...

Comment: Oh, Damn you are right, It looks like jquery doesn;t work at all, not just the carousel library, hm ...

Comment: If you open the console (in inspect element) and reload the page, what does it say?

Comment: It says nothing... Or I cannot see nothing.. maybe It'll be easier for you to look directly into the website.  http://inwestycyjneprzebudzenie.pl

Comment: Wow, you've got about 4 different versions of jQuery being loaded (though they do seem to load OK), and an error `TypeError: $(...).jCarouselLite is not a function` meaning there is a conflict with another javascript somewhere.

Comment: yea I guess so as well, but why Is it only on Firefox, and why does It randomly?

Answer (score 0):

So we've found that the problem is due to a conflict in jQuery. As the site uses wordpress, `noConflict` is usually enabled by default, but using the `$` operator is not permitted.

Instead use the wrapper;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // code here
});
```

around your initialisation code.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: So It should be like that `jQuery(function($) {
     $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
     auto: 3000,
speed: 1000,
vertical: true,
   });
});`  right ? So with this It stopped working eveon on chrome ;< I just have no idea what's going on here ;<

Comment: Yes, if that's all your code. I can see a bit more in the inspector, but perhaps that's not being used.

Comment: ehh, i guess i'm going to bed, maybe It will work tomorrow xD

Comment: You need to put it around the entire `$(document).ready(function(){...}`.